# column exist but when migration it returns SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column doesn't exist in table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

column exist but when migration it returns

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column doesn't exist in table

when i remove foreign key the problem is solved

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('skill_name')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('skill_note')->nullable();           
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('skill_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id ')
                ->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('skill_id');
            $table->foreign('skill_id')
                ->references('id')->on('skills');
            $table->decimal('note')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show your migrations for `skills` and `users`

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: @aynber done please help :(

Comment: @kerbholz version 6

Comment: If you have done any modifications on the skills or users table since your last migrate you have to run the command `php artisan migrate:fresh`. Because it seems to me like everything should go well with the code you have provided. Also make sure your `skill_user` migration is run after the other tables.

Comment: @RobertKujawa the error already is the return of fresh migration

Comment: It seems that table may not be in order. Make sure the skill_user migration run after the other migrations.

Comment: @sd077 yeah made sure of that

Comment: Is still same problem ?

Comment: @sd077 yes it's still

Comment: It doesn't seem any problem with the code. Try deleting the vendor folder and run composer install. And run php artisan migrate:fresh.

Answer (score 0):

In version 6 (the one you're using for what I could read in the comments), the increments('id') method doesn't create a Unsigned Integer, it rather creates a Unsigned Big Integer, therefore you need to change your foreign keys to

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('skill_id');
```

Comment: increments create unsignedInteger and bigIncrements create unsignedBigInteger so the above is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```html
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('skill_id')->unsigned();
```

If it does not work, I would suggest to run composer install and migrate:fresh